# validate unique combination of two fields in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

[image: This is the database table named "student_session" please see the screenshot]

I have 3 session 2019, 2020 and 2021 in every session I have student. My question is how to validate this sql wherein, when I promote the 2019 to 2020 the system will not allow to update because the data is already exist.

Let's say column session_id = 1 then student_id = 1 this is valid because this is not yet inserted but when inserted again the same value which is "session_id = 1 then student_id = 1" again this data will not allowed in validation.

```
 $class_id = $request->class_id;
 $class_section= $request->class_section;
 $promotion= $request->promoted_session;
 $promote = $request->input('student_checkbox');

 $this->validate($request, [            
    'student_checkbox' => 'unique:student_sessions,student_id,student_sessions,student_id',
 ]);
```

Comment: Create unique index by the field combination and use REPLACE INTO.

Comment: can you give me idea how to do that please

Comment: I have said how it may be implemented on the MySQL level. But I don't know how it looks in Laravel syntax (as a last resort this can be done шт raw SQL form).

Comment: i was thinking about the answer is in mysql or laravel validation so i tagged my question in mysql also

Comment: If the condition that the combination (session_id, student_id) must be unique is systematic then this MUST be checked on the database level - by proper unique index in the table structure. If such index exists then MySQL can automatically update existing record instead of duplicate insertion using REPLACE INTO or INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Search Laravel documentation for how these query types are mapped to Laravel code.

Comment: im looking for the code also because if you will give me your idea it is hard for me todo. as i checked they are using rule validation .